# ActiveStorage's rails_blob_url returning a link that shows a page with 404 error when opened

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I have an attachment, that is passed to the frontend through a serializer as follows.

```
module NameOfSerializer
  class Base < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id,
               ...
               ...
               ...
               :attachment_url

    def attachment_url
      Rails.application
           .routes.url_helpers
           .rails_blob_url(object.attachment, host: ENV['HOST_URL'])
    end
  end
end
```

On development and staging, it works perfectly. I can copy paste the URL and one can open and view the attachment.
But on production, it's showing a page with 404 error.

This is what I found in the AWS Elastic Beanstalk log.

```
[2019-02-04T03:50:38.733073 #16644]  INFO -- : [4ca0d491-66cc-4594-9db4-75da533d2fbc] Started GET "/rails/active_storage/blobs/insert_signed_id_here/20190131_214818%20copy%202.jpg" at 2019-02-04 03:50:38 +0000
I, [2019-02-04T03:50:38.736005 #16644]  INFO -- : [4ca0d491-66cc-4594-9db4-75da533d2fbc] Processing by ActiveStorage::BlobsController#show as JPEG
I, [2019-02-04T03:50:38.736056 #16644]  INFO -- : [4ca0d491-66cc-4594-9db4-75da533d2fbc]   Parameters: {"signed_id"=>"insert the signed_id here", "filename"=>"20190131_214818 copy 2"}
D, [2019-02-04T03:50:38.737552 #16644] DEBUG -- : [4ca0d491-66cc-4594-9db4-75da533d2fbc]   [1m[36mActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.9ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]]
I, [2019-02-04T03:50:38.737936 #16644]  INFO -- : [4ca0d491-66cc-4594-9db4-75da533d2fbc] Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
F, [2019-02-04T03:50:38.740120 #16644] FATAL -- : [4ca0d491-66cc-4594-9db4-75da533d2fbc]   
F, [2019-02-04T03:50:38.740163 #16644] FATAL -- : [4ca0d491-66cc-4594-9db4-75da533d2fbc] ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find ActiveStorage::Blob with 'id'=16):
F, [2019-02-04T03:50:38.740185 #16644] FATAL -- : [4ca0d491-66cc-4594-9db4-75da533d2fbc]   
F, [2019-02-04T03:50:38.740215 #16644] FATAL -- : [4ca0d491-66cc-4594-9db4-75da533d2fbc] activerecord (5.2.0) lib/active_record/core.rb:177:in `find'
```

I was surprised to see that the log says the Blob with id `16` isn't found, but when I ran `rails c` on Elastic Beanstalk, I found the blob.
I also tested another way of retrieving the file from S3 in rails console by running `attachment.service_url`.
I was able to access the attachment. Didn't run into 404 errors.

Any ideas? I encountered this issue before and for that issue, I changed to using `service_url` but I'd like to know what's causing `rails_blob_url` to not work on production environment.

Comment: can you share the generated url when you call rails_blob_url ?

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea. Not sure if this helps, but this is how the URL would look, just replace `example `and `signed_id`. @F.E.A

With `rails_blob_url`:
`https://api.example.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/signed_id/20190131_214818%20copy%202.jpg`

With `service_url`:
`https://bucket-name.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/key?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D%2220190131_214818%20copy%202.jpg%22%3B%20filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%2720190131_214818%2520copy%25202.jpg&response-content-type=image%2Fjpeg...`

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this. Here's how I fixed it for my project.

First, I'm using Amazon S3 for production, **but also development**. That second part is crucial.

In other words, my `config/environments/development.rb` had this:

```rb
# Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
# config.active_storage.service = :local
config.active_storage.service = :amazon
```

However, **this by itself is not enough**. For some reason, Rails *still* tries to use `local` when generating urls.

The workaround is to remove the `local` config. Here's what my `storage.yml` looks like afterwards:

```
# THE FIX: COMMENTED THIS OUT
# local:
#   service: Disk
#   root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

# Use rails credentials:edit to set the AWS secrets (as aws:access_key_id|secret_access_key)
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
  region: us-east-2
  bucket: xxx
```

After restarting the server, everything worked pleasantly.